# Validate 11 Digits in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

Might be a simple question, but I can't find an answer that fits this bit of code :(

I need to validate a phone number to have EXACTLY 11 digits (no letters)

```
    function validateForm3() {
  var x=document.forms["booking"]["number"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please fill in 11 numbers");
  return false;
  }
   var x=document.forms["booking"]["email"].value;
if (x.indexOf("@")=== -1)
  {
  alert("Please enter a valid email");
  return false;
  }
}
```

I can't really change the structure of this, so it needs to fit into this bit of code :( any suggestions or answers is greatly appeciated :)

Comment: YOU ARE ALL AMAZING! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`regexp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
if (! /^[0-9]{11}$/.test(x)) {
  alert("Please input exactly 11 numbers!");
  return false;
}
```

Note that you're intentionally excluding a lot of phone numbers, including international ones or alternative writing styles of phone numbers you could reach. You should really just test for `/^\+?[0-9]+$/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!/^\d{11}$/.test(x)) 
    alert('These are not 11 digits!');
else 
    alert('Passed!');
```

Try it 
http://jsfiddle.net/LKAPN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use regex:

```
"1234".match(/^\d{4}$/);
```

Explanation:

```
^   - matches the beginning of the string
\d  - matches one digit
{4} - tells that we want four digits (you want thirteen then)
$   - matches the end of the string
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that:

```
var str = '12345678900';
if (str.match(/^\d{11}$/)) {
    // Valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
if (x.length == 11 && +x == x)
```

Answer (score 0):

kinda hacky, but you could do:

```
if(x.length==11)
{
    for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        if (parseInt(x[i])!=x[i])
        {
            alert("only enter numbers!");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    alert("must enter 11 digits!");
}
```

Comment: haha, of course I come up with a semi-convoluted method, completely ignoring regexp... hint: unless you're afraid of regexp for some reason, it's probably best to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can the use regular expression:

```
\d{11}
```

However, you probably also want to strip whitespace:

```
var isElevenNumbers = (/^\d{11}$/m.test(mynumber.replace(/\s]/g, '')));
```

And you may want to strip more for internation numbers, e.g. +1-234-567-9090

```
var isElevenNumbers = (/^\d{11}$/m.test(mynumber.replace(/[\s\+\-]/g, '')));
```

where 'mynumber' is your variable holding the value.

Answer (score 0):

Steven Levithan has a very useful excerpt on Regexps that validate North American as well as international phone numbers at http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number .

That page is excerpted from his book *Regular Expressions Cookbook* (O'Reilly, 2009)